# Обычный массив VS std::array

Tags: c++

Используют ли вообще на практике шаблон `std::array`? Если да, то почему? И быстрее ли он работает, чем обычные массивы?

Comment: используют, не быстрее.

Comment: , и не медленнее

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Шаблон `std::array` позволяет использовать родной (сишный) тип массива (`T[]`) в качестве [объекта первого класса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0). Т.е. такой объект можно передавать в функцию и возвращать из неё, не боясь неявного преобразования массива к указателю и тем самым потери размерности.

`std::array` это агрегатный тип, т.е. не имеющий пользовательских конструкторов и по сути является обычной обёрткой над сишным массивом. На практике это обычно означает, что никакой лишней вычислительной нагрузки в runtime это не несёт, но и быстрее сырого массива он работать не может.

Comment: я думаю, что ссылка на его [исходники](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00752_source.html) (один с возможных) сильно прояснит ситуацию.